# Issue with PictureBox control

Tags: c#, image, crop, picturebox

I have image file that i wanna crop and load to `picturebox`. When i download it remotely - all work fine, but when i load it from local machine - `picturebox` pic stretch...

```
 var img = (Bitmap) Image.FromStream(new WebClient().OpenRead("https://i.snag.gy/MjJca5.jpg"));

  img = CropImage(img);

  BackgroundImage = img;
  BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;

  public Bitmap CropImage(Image img) {
   // create a graphic path to hold the shape data
   GraphicsPath path = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
   var points = new Point[] {
    new Point(85, 1111), new Point(934, 1111), new Point(934, 952), new Point(1642, 952),
     new Point(1642, 2000), new Point(85, 2000), new Point(85, 1111)
   };
   GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
   gp.AddPolygon(points.ToArray());

   Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(2220, 2220);

   using(Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp1)) {
    G.Clip = new Region(gp);
    G.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
    bmp1.Save("axi.jpeg");
    return bmp1;
   }
  }
```

This code return this pic. All work correctly

[image]

but this code return this pic.

```
 FileStream file = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open);
    var img = (Bitmap) Image.FromStream(file);

    img = CropImage(img);
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = img;
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
...
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure both mages have the same dpi resolution!

Comment: images are similar

Comment: Did you actually check the dpi?

Comment: before crop - 300dpi, after - 96

Comment: Thought so. This may not be the only probelm but it surely is one. Add this: `bmp1.SetResolution(300, 300);` after creating it or else the coordinates won't fit the image.. ((or maybe `bmp1.SetResolution(img.HorizontalResolution, img.VerticalResolution);` ))

Comment: this code work with all jpeg files, but nots work with tiff-file. http://www.filedropper.com/165173z

Comment: This file has 6 pages. You may need some extra code to access the pages one by one. There are posts on how to read multi-page tif files; try to google it!

Comment: i extract first page. Same situation